How to write comments on a @typedef for Closure compiler?
Here is how you define a custom type, from the Closure compiler documentation:
/** 
 * @typedef {{
 *            foo:string,
 *            bar:number,
 *            foobar: (number|string)
 *          }}
 */
var Mytype;

How do I add comments to explain what each property does, preferably on the same line as each property?

A @typedef can certainly be used this way, but consider a @record instead - and if needed, @typedef the record to another name. You can add more remarks in the jsdoc block you've written already, but not specifically for each member.
What you've built here is an anonymous structural type, and then used typedef to give it a (new) name. Specifically, this is a record type when defined using this "object literal" syntax.
Instead, consider defining an explicit type, such as with @record, allowing you to add more remarks :
/**
 * A short note about what this structural interface is for.
 * @record
 */
function Mytype() {}
/**
 * A string, used for foo things.
 * @type {string}
 */
Mytype.prototype.foo;
/**
 * The number of a bar, or something.
 * @type {number}
 */
Mytype.prototype.bar;
/**
 * A field with a union type
 * @type {number|string}
 */
Mytype.prototype.foobar;

Be aware that structural types can have implications on the rest of your program - it may be beneficial to define a nominal type (e.g. a class with a constructor) to give the compiler more knowledge and control over what the code can be allowed to do. Simply changing the above to be declared as an @interface or using a @constructor (possibly as an es5 class) will be enough to declare such a type - but then you must use it, instead of passing object literals. It will have the advantage of avoiding permitting the compiler to consider two unrelated types (where has a subset of the fields of the other) as being related, and thus allowing the "wrong" type to be substituted. Beyond allowing "the wrong type" to be passed, it also prevents some optimizations from being applied. Simple example: if one type is never directly instantiated, uses of that type can always be marked as null, but if a subtype apparently exists and is used, then those usages can't be optimized out.

Thanks Colin. Most of my class constructors use a single argument object that is destructured: constructor({arg1, arg2, arg3}) { }. To not have to repeat the JSDoc for every class that inherits from this class, I want to create a (a)typedef I can reuse. This turned out to be very awkward because of the Closure compiler syntax. I want to write each argument and its comment on one line only, so something more compact than your suggestion. If Closure had supported (a)property this would have been very easy.

You may be able to get away with two lines each, as /** @type {string} */ is valid to make jsdoc a single line - but I question if you can fit enough words to be substantially more useful than just a well named property. Ideally your IDE is writing the block for you, to be written once and read (by tooling and downstream writers passing in args) many times as concisely as you like. The point about structured types and impeding optimization is probably best as a separate discussion to how simple the syntax could have been if (15 years ago) you had designed it yourself ;).

That's understandable. Thanks anyway Colin.
